# Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a metro server or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release

Tags: android, react-native, apk

[image]

Hello have you experienced this error after generate an apk with command `./gradlew assembleDebug` ??

I just see this error after download the apk on my android phone...

"react-native": "~0.61.5",

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The apk that you built is still debug version.

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Thats why it still need the metro server to debug and run normally.

If you want to test out a release version of the apk you need to build and run the apk in release mode:

Either, build a signed apk
https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android
or

Let react native run a release variant on your device(you may still need metro server)

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

If the above command doesn't work try:

```
react-native run-android --configuration=release
```

Comment: This is the real answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Recently I tried to create and run in windows 10 by referring the link https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. I too face same issue and I figure out that this is because by default mobile device try to search build in port 8081. So I gave this command to change the port and run
**npx react-native run-android --port=1234** and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

npx react-native run-android --port=1234

go to android folder ./gradlew clean

and go back to your project

and npx run react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the Android SDK path to my `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc`:

`export ANDROID_SDK=/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk export PATH=/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem because I was not starting the Reactive Native service itself.

You can run directly:

```
react-native start
```

Metro will give you the option to run on Android.